# When I start Milvus Cluster by helm, I encounter this error "0/4 nodes are available: 4 node(s) didn't satisfy existing pods anti-affinity rules."

Tags: database, kubernetes, vector

I follow [this link](https://milvus.io/docs/v2.0.0/install_cluster-helm.md) to install milvus cluster. When I execute this command "helm install my-release milvus/milvus" ,I find that a pod never started successfully.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLzru.png)

```
$ kubectl get pod | grep lcl
lcl-release-milvus-querynode-56b9b4d54d-9r7jl      0/1     Pending            0                6h31m here
```

Then I use "kubectl describe pods lcl-release-milvus-querynode-56b9b4d54d-9r7jl" to get the following info.

```
$ kubectl describe pods lcl-release-milvus-querynode-56b9b4d54d-9r7j
0/4 nodes are available: 4 node(s) didn't satisfy existing pods anti-affinity rules.
```

Who can help me analyze the problem?

Comment: Without seeing any of the relevant source code, Kubernetes manifests, or Helm charts, it's a little hard to tell.  Can you edit the question to replace the links with a [mcve], so all of the required details are in the question itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on the milvus chart, only the `etcd` has the affinity setup, but your "queryNode" also has the affinity set? You need to remove the affinity that you have set [here](https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus-helm/blob/2b813fb30bf8986d02033377d1cc0077e8bc7d17/charts/milvus/values.yaml#L237) for queryNode.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I found there is one another milvus release in my k8s cluster. That release configured the pods-anti-affinity rules in the QueryNode area, and after I removed those rules, all the pods in my release started normally.